# Converting expression to only use NAND gates

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

How would I go about converting this Boolean expression so that it would only use NAND gates in its circuit?

A ⋅ ¬B ⋅ ¬D + ¬A ⋅ B ⋅ ¬C ⋅ D

Comment: Take deMorgan's on it.

Answer (score 2):

If your expression was: \$f = ¬A ⋅ ¬B ⋅ C ⋅ D + A ⋅ B ⋅ ¬C\$

$$¬A ⋅ ¬B ⋅ C ⋅ D + A ⋅ B ⋅ ¬C$$
deMorgans: Invert expression, change + to ⋅ and invert terms.

$$\overline {\overline {¬A ⋅ ¬B ⋅ C ⋅ D} ⋅ \overline {A ⋅ B ⋅ ¬C}}$$

All NANDs.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you have to apply deMorgan's theorem in order to have only NAND gates.
I don't want to solve your expresion but I can give you an example:
[image] will be
[image]
that will be
[image]

So you have to invert the expressions and change + (OR) with * (AND) .